# mutate across columns - if condition met return column name as value

Tags: r, dplyr, across

I have a wide data frame similar to document term matrix:

```
df_names_tkns <-  tibble::tribble(
                                ~name, ~aaa, ~ddd, ~downing, ~eee, ~london, ~street, ~bbb, ~broadway, ~ccc, ~new, ~york,
  "AAA LONDON DOWNING STREET DDD EEE",   1L,   1L,       1L,   1L,      1L,      1L,   NA,        NA,   NA,   NA,    NA,
      "AAA NEW YORK BROADWAY BBB CCC",   1L,   NA,       NA,   NA,      NA,      NA,   1L,        1L,   1L,   1L,    1L
  )
```

I would like to replace bulk in all columns where x > 0 the value into the name of the column. What would be the correct syntax? I have tried the following two approaches, with if and with case_when.

```r
   df_names_tkns2 <- df_names_tkns |> 
      mutate(across(2:ncol(df_names_tkns),
      function (x)  if (x > 0) cur_column(x) else x))
```

The error quote:

```
Caused by error in `across()`:
! Problem while computing column `aaa`.
Caused by error in `if (x > 0) ...`:
! the condition has length > 1
```

Or I tried

```
df_names_tkns2 <- df_names_tkns |> 
  mutate(
    across(
      2:ncol(df_names_tkns), 
      ~ case_when(.x > 1 ~  cur_column(.x))                              )
      )
    )
```

Error quote:

```
Caused by error in `across()`:
! Problem while computing column `aaa`.
Caused by error in `cur_column()`:
! unused argument (aaa)
```

Apparently I am not using the right syntax for writing the function. What would be the correct way?

Comment: `cur_column()` does not take any arguments.  You also want to use the vectorized `ifelse()` as you're testing multiple values per column rather than a single value.  Untested but `df_names_tkns |> mutate(across(-1, ~ifelse(.x > 0, cur_column(), .x)))` should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you're getting is caused by passing a vector with length greater than one to `if()`.

For example:

```r
if(c(TRUE, FALSE)) print("true")
# Error in if (c(TRUE, FALSE)) print("true") : the condition has length > 1
```

To avoid this you can either:

1. Group your data frame by row
2. Use vectorised logic

### 1. Group data frame by row

Using `dplry::rowwise()`. This will ensure that only one value is passed to `if()` at a time.

```r
df_names_tkns2 <-
      df_names_tkns |> 
      rowwise() |>
      mutate(across(2:ncol(df_names_tkns),
      # ^ NB consider across(2:last_col(), ...) for brevity
      function (x)  if (x > 0) cur_column(x) else x))
```

### 2. Use vectorised logic

`if_else()` is a function that vectorises `if()`/`else()` logic. So you could do:

```r
df_names_tkns2 <- df_names_tkns |> 
      mutate(across(2:ncol(df_names_tkns),
      function (x)  if_else(x > 0, cur_column(), x)))
```

#### A note about `cur_column()`

`cur_column()` does not take an argument - some of the latter errors you were getting were caused by the unnamed argument `aaa` being passed to `cur_column()`. This is because you were passing values (such as `aaa`) to `cur_column()` via `function(x) cur_column(x)` within your call to `mutate()`. Since `cur_column()` doesn't take any arguments, it crashes when you pass `x` to it.

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution using `purrr::imap_dfc`

```r
df_names_tkns |>
    mutate(purrr::imap_dfc(df_names_tkns[-1], ~ifelse(.x > 0, .y, .x)))

##> + # A tibble: 2 × 12
##>   name  aaa   ddd   downing eee   london street bbb   broadway ccc   new   york 
##>   <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>   <chr> <chr>  <chr>  <chr> <chr>    <chr> <chr> <chr>
##> 1 AAA … aaa   ddd   downing eee   london street NA    NA       NA    NA    NA   
##> 2 AAA … aaa   NA    NA      NA    NA     NA     bbb   broadway ccc   new   york
```

Comment: Thank you, also great answer to my question.